# What would happen to the turn-on transient if I add a capacitor in parallel to a transformer?

Tags: transformer, power-factor-correction, inrush-current

I have a welder with a big air gapped transformer. Input specs: 220V, 3200 W active, 25 A total (cos Phi 0.56). Output specs: at full load 110 A welding current. I haven't checked whether output is DC pulsed (simple rectification) or is AC, but the electrode connector is marked as "ground" and the clip ("pinza") as such, so I guess it's rectified. The welder is rated for "intermittent" use for 3.2 mm electrodes, and continuous for 2.5 mm electrodes.

When I switch it on, if the current is set to more than 50% of full scale, the overload switch in the garage trips.

Also, at full power the total input current (25 A) poses a strain on the standard plug that is provided (16 A power plug, I wonder... '70s safety I guess).

I could add a capacitor of about 150-200 uF to improve the average power factor during use and reduce strain on the plug and wires, but what would happen to the inrush current?

Since in the transient no magnetic field is present and the transformer is like a plain wire, I would expect no change in the inrush current, therefore requiring a soft-start circuit.

Comment: Re: "'70s safety" -- more likely DIY ignorance. Don't continue that practice.

Comment: Can you tell us more about the transformer? What are the input and output specs? It's possible you've listed the output specs, and the input specs are a higher voltage at a lower current.

Comment: @PeteBecker It is a commercial monophase welder from 1974, rated 3.2 kW (active), therefore tuned to the common single phase power limit in the country where it was built. The cable and plug looked original... It has been designed that way, no DIY!

Comment: @HeathRaftery I edited/added as requested.

Comment: Just like connecting the transformer (inductor) draws AC current (apparent power), so would adding capacitance.  The two together might improve [power factor](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_factor) but only *after* a *bigger* initial surge, due to the added load of the cap.  Unfortunately this is not going to help the plug and breaker issue. Upgrade both to safer, bigger, and more up-to-code versions, possibly the service feed as well. (I ran 8 gauge to my garage for 40A service, de-rated to 30A.)

Comment: @rdtsc I don't want to upgrade the plug... it would make the device usable only in places where a 32A socket is available, even if the active power is within household limits. Correcting the power factor seems better in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transformer inrush typically has little to do with the load on the secondary. So the capacitor would have to go on the primary to have any effect. On the primary it will undoubtedly increase inrush current, though probably for a shorter period than the transformer. That's because at the point the device is turned on there will be an instantaneous voltage applied to the capacitor, making for a dramatic rate of change from zero. Capacitor impedance falls as rate of voltage change increases, so it will be close to zero in this case. The only thing limiting the current then is the series resistance.

The best way to reduce transformer inrush (which is caused by the delay establishing a corresponding magnetic field) is with an inrush current limiter. The three basic inrush current limiters are, in rough order of complexity: a fixed resistor with a time-delayed relay across it to short it out after the inrush period; a NTC thermistor; which automatically falls in resistance over time due to heat; and an electronic soft-starter.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about the additional inrush. In fact, in the initial transient, both transformer and capacitor act as pure resistances. I guess I'll use a timed relay with a resistor, which at this point has to be quite huge, considering the surge. I could use two relays to connect the capacitor after the initial inductive surge, and disconnect the resistor only after both surges are gone. However, since the surge will be smaller but longer, the resistor may need to be just as big.